# Why In Mailcore2 Sample the 'MCOMessageView' file is a c++ file instead of objective c one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mailcore2, mailcore

I'm checking the source code from mailcore 2 sample demo. The IOS project has a class 'MCOMessageView.mm'. It's a very good helper class with a webview and a few delegates for html rendering. So why use 'mm' as its file extension since it doesn't contain any c++ code.

Comment: Because reasons.  In what way is this conceived to be a valid question for SO?

Comment: @Avi The sample project was made by mailcore2's engineers. I wonder what's their considerations when setting this class of extension 'mm'.

Comment: Matters of speculation are off-topic.  Ask mailcore's engineers.

Comment: @Avi  Mailcore engineers prefer to answer questions in stackoverflow as they mentioned in github.

Comment: Their engineers can't set policy for SO.  I happen to agree with Florian's answer, but this question is still inappropriate, as it's pure speculation, nor is it addressing a programming problem.

Comment: @Avi. It's indeed a programming problem since some mailcore genius developers can sometimes share their thoughts and their preferences of coding. It might be helpful for some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some developers, used to deal with ObjC++, use the .mm extension by default for their ObjC class, even if no C++ code is needed, so that they can use ObjC++ later on if needed.

MailCore uses ObjC++ by default, so .mm extension for class by default even if at their is no C++ code in it at the time, it can be added in the future.

It as virtually no cost a run time, so it's.. just a way of doing things. And since LVVM, it has but little cost at build time

Another possibility is that their was C++ in a previous version of the file and, commit after commit, C++ code was replace and they didn't bother renaming the class because they can still add some C++ code in the future and they want to keep their hand free.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using .mm is that it will hint Xcode that it needs the C++ runtime to link the final binary.
If I used .m, I would have to pass a flag explicitly.